# C - getting prime numbers using this algorithm

Tags: c, primes

I am fighting some simple question.
I want to get prime numbers

I will use this algorithm
[image]

and...  I finished code writing like this.

```
int k = 0, x = 1, n, prim, lim = 1;
int p[100000];
int xCount=0, limCount=0, kCount=0;

p[0] = 2;
scanf("%d", &n);

start = clock();
do
{
    x += 2; xCount++;
    if (sqrt(p[lim]) <= x)
    {
        lim++; limCount++;
    }
    k = 2; prim = true;
    while (prim && k<lim)
    {

        if (x % p[k] == 0)
            prim = false;
        k++; kCount++;
    }
    if (prim == true)
    {
        p[lim] = x;
        printf("prime number : %d\n", p[lim]);
    }
} while (k<n);
```

I want to check how much repeat this code (x+=2; lim++; k++;) 
so I used xCount, limCount, kCount variables.

when input(n) is 10, the results are x : 14, lim : 9, k : 43. wrong answer.

answer is (14,3,13).

Did I write code not well?
tell me correct point plz...

Comment: the most obvious thing different is there no `for` loop using `i`

Comment: The first time you reach `sqrt(p[lim])` that is `p[1]` which is uninitialised.

Comment: um... i think 'lim' substitues 'i'

Comment: How many mistakes did you spot in the code you're using as a reference?  It looks like Pascal, but it isn't compilable, even assuming suitable preambles.  (The assignment `prim := "x is not divisible by p[k]"` is particularly problematic; there's also at least one comparison where an assignment is intended.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks but I can't understand English well, I have to find problems myself.

Comment: Do not damage/destroy a question after you have an answer or some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adapt an algorithm to your needs, it's always a good idea to implement it verbatim first, especially if you have pseudocode that is detailed enough to allow for such a verbatim translation into C-code (even more so with Fortran but I digress)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void){
    // type index 1..n
    int index;
    // var
    // x: integer
    int x;
    //i, k, lim: integer
    int i, k, lim;
    // prim: boolean
    bool prim;
    // p: array[index] of integer {p[i] = i'th prime number}
    /*
       We cannot do that directly, we need to know the value of "index" first
    */
    int res;

    res = scanf("%d", &index);
    if(res != 1 || index < 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Only integral values >= 1, please. Thank you.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /*
       The array from the pseudocode is a one-based array, take care
    */
    int p[index + 1];
    // initialize the whole array with distinguishable values in case of debugging
    for(i = 0;i<index;i++){
       p[i] = -i;
    }
    /*
        Your variables
    */
    int lim_count = 0, k_count = 0;

    // begin
    // p[1] = 2
    p[1] = 2;
    // write(2)
    puts("2");
    // x = 1
    x = 1;
    // lim = 1
    lim = 1;
    // for i:=2 to n do
    for(i = 2;i < index; i++){
       // repeat (until prim)
       do {
          // x = x + 2
          x += 2;
          // if(sqr(p[lim]) <= x) then
          if(p[lim] * p[lim] <= x){
             // lim = lim +1
             lim++;
             lim_count++;
          }
          // k = 2
          k = 2;
          // prim = true
          prim = true;
          // while (prim and (k < lim)) do
          while (prim && (k < lim)){
             // prim = "x is not divisible by p[k]"
             if((x % p[k]) == 0){
                prim = false;
             }
             // k = k + 1
             k++;
             k_count++;
          }
       // (repeat) until prim
       } while(!prim);
       // p[i] := x
       p[i] = x;
       // write(x)
       printf("%d\n",x);
    }
    // end

    printf("x = %d, lim_count =  %d, k_count =  %d \n",x,lim_count,k_count);

    for(i = 0;i<index;i++){
       printf("%d, ",p[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It will print an `index - 1` number of primes starting at 2.

You can easily change it now--for example: print only the primes up to `index` instead of `index - 1` primes.

In your case the numbers for all six primes up to 13 gives

```
x = 13, lim_count =  2, k_count =  3
```

which is distinctly different from the result you want.

Comment: int *p; p = (int*)malloc(index + 1);  I used this code. And I entered input 11 then I can get (14,3,13). It was answer of input 10. But I guess this code is right because of difference 1 based arrays or 0 based arrays. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation looks very sloppy.

---

```
for i:= 2 to n do begin
```

must translate to:

```
for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
```

---

```
repeat
    ....
until prim
```

must translate to:

```
do {
    ...
} while (!prim);
```

---

The `while prim...` loop is *inside* the `repeat...until prim` loop.

I leave it to you to apply this to your code and to check that all constructs have been properly translated. it doesn't look too difficult to do that correctly.

Note: it looks like the algorithm uses 1-based arrays whereas C uses 0-based arrays.

Comment: but it doesn't match answer. I think I can't convert from 1-based arrays to 0-based arrays.

Comment: @COOOPS You can create an array 1 larger and just simply not use the first position, as an initial phase. Translating between 1-based and 0-based is not an easy problem, as far as I have seen in translating between C++ and Matlab...